# Quirk with KeyDown event timing, how can I bypass it?

Tags: c#, events, timing

I have a method which decreases the value of a variable while a key is pressed (such as the spacebar). The variable is displayed on a label in a windows form. Trouble is, when I hold down the key, the label shows the decreased variable, waits for about half a second, then starts updating the label rapidly if the key is still held down. Is there a way I can eliminate the half second wait in between the first event and the rest? I am happy to provide code if it is needed to fix the issue.

Comment: Are you sure there's not a KeyPress event involved in there? It sounds like the keyboard Repeat Delay is causing the behavior you're seeing. You should be able to create a timer that starts when KeyDown is triggered and changes the label at even intervals until KeyUp is triggered.

Comment: I think this will be caused by Windows handling key presses. Control Panel -> Keyboard -> Repeat Speed. But there can be a way to bypass it in C#.

Comment: @itsme86, yes, I'm using the KeyDown event to check if the key is being pressed.